# Avoiding hidden controls by virtual keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-softkeyboard

In my application there are some EditText controls. When virtual keyboard appears it hides some of these controls.
How can I "shink" my display to avoid this?
My base layout is LinearLayout.
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `adjustResize` value for `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml` for your activity :

```
<activity ... android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

[image]

Comment: I've found the answer here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html